# Over lap td with colspan="3"

Tags: html, css

Previously I was using below css to hide adjacent td it is working fine for colspan="2", but I need the same to be worked for colspan="3".

Do I need to add anything in the css or to the td?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    td[colspan="3"]+td{
      display: none;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings1</th>
         <th>Savings2</th>
         <th>Savings3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Sum: $180</td>
         <td>$80</td>

        <td >$110</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: your question? how do you want your table to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to hide two td so using this

```
 td[colspan="3"]+td{
          display: none;
        }
            td[colspan="3"]+td+td{
          display: none;
        }
```

```css
table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    td[colspan="3"]+td{
      display: none;
    }
        td[colspan="3"]+td+td{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings1</th>
         <th>Savings2</th>
         <th>Savings3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Sum: $180</td>
         <td>$80</td>

        <td >$110</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: @SampathSam Welcome